# write a SQL query that fetch all the bookings with their price, pickup_location, delivery location, and the price variance

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, subquery

Given a table booking and a table shipment_log, knowing that the shipment updates may occur and are logged into the shipment_log table, write a SQL query that fetch all the bookings with their price, pickup_location, delivery location, and the price variance. Table descriptions:

```
CREATE TABLE booking (
booking_id integer,
price numeric,
PRIMARY KEY (booking_id)
); 


CREATE TABLE shipment_log (
log_id integer NOT NULL,
booking_id integer,
pickup_city varchar,
pickup_state varchar,
delivery_city varchar,
delivery_state varchar,
"timestamp" timestamp,
price numeric,
PRIMARY KEY (log_id),
CONSTRAINT FK_booking FOREIGN KEY (booking_id)
REFERENCES booking(booking_id));
```

My Query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT booking.booking_id,
booking.price,shipment_log.pickup_city,
shipment_log.pickup_state,shipment_log.delivery_city,
shipment_log.delivery_state
FROM booking, shipment_log
WHERE booking.booking_id = shipment_log.booking_id
AND booking.price = shipment_log.price;
```

But I am not able to calculate the price variance within this query

Separate Query for Variance:

```
SELECT  VARIANCE(price)           
FROM shipment_log
GROUP By booking_id;
```

Can anyone please help me write a nested query for this one. Or how should I try to  get the desired output?

I have imported the data from csv files.
Data:(It's large data for shipment_log, hence I am attaching few samples)

```
enter code here

booking: 
booking_id  price
1   1350
2   1600
3   4700
4   550
5   6000
6   5000
7   2500
8   6500
9   3000
10  3100
11  6000
12  425
13  1000
14  950
15  3000
16  1950
17  5600
18  3000
19  3500
20  2100
21  5000
22  5600
23  550
24  2200
25  5300
26  1000
27  5000
28  1000
```

shipment_log:

```
enter code here
log_id  booking_id  pickup_city pickup_state    delivery_city    
delivery_state  log_timestamp   price
75095244    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-03-09 15:03:36.491+00  1350
75097084    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-03-07 20:06:00.874+00  1450
75096376    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-03-02 23:31:26.025+00  1400
75095248    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-02-23 21:37:54.65+00   1400
75097140    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-02-23 21:35:41.283+00  1225
75097252    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-02-19 13:39:12.514+00  1400
75094692    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-02-19 13:35:09.376+00  1300
75096388    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-02-16 15:49:19.613+00  1500
75096440    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-02-09 22:10:01.971+00  1100
75094728    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-02-09 15:51:15.866+00  1500
75096432    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-02-05 14:05:49.521+00  1100
75094764    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-02-02 16:58:53.096+00  1610
75096500    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-01-27 15:52:46.319+00  1100
75094820    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-01-19 20:18:36.112+00  1750
75096580    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-01-19 20:16:13.837+00  1700
75095552    1   Akron   OH  Statesville NC  2018-01-19 20:08:18.841+00  2000
75096336    2   Brighton    MI  Statesville NC  2018-03-02 22:43:11.297+00   
1600
75095356    2   Brighton    MI  Statesville NC  2018-02-22 18:25:48.821+00   
1600
75097284    2   Brighton    MI  Statesville NC  2018-02-17 14:15:00.722+00   
1750
75094744    2   Brighton    MI  Statesville NC  2018-02-09 19:34:53.796+00   
1600
75095528    2   Brighton    MI  Statesville NC  2018-01-26 15:10:16.254+00   
1600
75097436    2   Brighton    MI  Statesville NC  2018-01-26 14:17:53.284+00   
1600
75096812    2   Brighton    MI  Statesville NC  2018-01-19 17:13:12.875+00   
2272
75096540    2   Brighton    MI  Statesville NC  2018-01-19 17:09:38.037+00   
1600
```

Comment: Can you please post the sample insert code for both table as well. This will make a lot easier.

Comment: attached the sample

Comment: I have imported data from csv files

Answer (score 0):

If you have given any sample data it would be better to verify the result. You can try

```
SELECT DISTINCT booking.booking_id,
booking.price,
shipment_log.pickup_city,
shipment_log.pickup_state,
shipment_log.delivery_city,
shipment_log.delivery_state,
(SELECT  VARIANCE(shipment_log.price)           
FROM shipment_log join booking on 
booking.`booking_id`=shipment_log.`booking_id`
GROUP By shipment_log.booking_id) as 'variance'
FROM booking, shipment_log
WHERE booking.booking_id = shipment_log.booking_id
AND booking.price = shipment_log.price;
```

This is working on sequel pro.[image]

Comment: I ran your query, I got the following error ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

Comment: If you post above data within sql insert statement it would be easy to verify the result rather than just exporting to csv file. Its very time consuming  to convert them into insert statement. Other option you can export on sql format.

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate the variance then join it to your original query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT booking.booking_id,
booking.price,shipment_log.pickup_city,
shipment_log.pickup_state,shipment_log.delivery_city,
shipment_log.delivery_state, tab.varPrice
FROM booking
INNER JOIN shipment_log
ON booking.booking_id = shipment_log.booking_id
AND booking.price = shipment_log.price
INNER JOIN   (select booking_id,
     VARIANCE(price) as varPrice
     from  shipment_log
     group by booking_id
     ) tab
ON tab.booking_id=booking.booking_id;
```